# How do you derive the Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, velocity, kinetic-theory

I have searched for a reasonable derivation online, but so far have been unable to find one which doesn't skip steps or presume prior knowledge.

I found a derivation on [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%E2%80%93Boltzmann_distribution) which gives the following relation as motivation for the rest of the equations:

$$-\log\Big(\frac{N_i}{N}\Big) \propto \frac{E_i}{T}$$

where $N_i$ is the expected number of particles in the single-particle microstate $i$, $N$ is the total number of particles in the system, $E_i$ is the energy of microstate $i$, and $T$ is the equilibrium temperature of the system.

This part intuitively makes sense to me, however, the next part of the derivation says you can gain the following by introducing a normalising factor:

$$\frac{N_i}{N} = \frac{\exp\big(\frac{-E_i}{k_BT}\big)}{\sum_j \exp\big(\frac{-E_j}{k_BT}\big)}$$

where $E_j$ is the energy of microstate $j$, and $k_B$ is the Boltzmann constant. What's the meaning behind this normalising factor, and how does its meaning motivate its use? What relation does it have to the Boltzmann constant?

Comment: It is derived in every statistical physics textbook.

Comment: @Roger Vadim What is you favourite example of such a book for simplicity of derivation with no skipped steps or assumed knowledge?

Comment: The normalization simply comes from the fact that $N = \sum_i N_i$

Comment: @BySymmetry Okay, that sort of makes sense, could you explain how one uses that to move from the upper relation, to the lower equation? Or are the two not as related as the Wikipedia article implies? In what sense is the Boltzmann constant related to the normalising factor? Thanks!

Comment: Every demonstration will skip some steps, that you are assumed to know if you are reading at that level. Otherwise books would become extremely long, and boring too

Comment: @Wolphramjonny Let's say I have an understanding of Undergraduate mathematics up to what is required for the average statistical mechanics course. What would be a good book on that level?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not remember well enough to advice you on that, it has been a very long time since I studied this subject

Comment: @Wolphramjonny Okay, thank you anyway, I will try and find a derivation and then update this thread with my own answer. I think it's important a good (thorough/ complete) derivation is easily searchable, with a physical explanation!

Comment: @Connor:  A common undergraduate text in the US is Schroeder's *An Introduction to Thermal Physics.*  It's highly readable and probably good for self-study.  The author assumes that the reader has taken "a year-long introductory physics course and a year of calculus", though multi-variable calculus is immensely helpful as well.  Boltzmann statistics (which is what you want) is in Chapter 6;  you'll probably need to read Chapters 1–3 before you dive into that, though.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Thanks! I am currently looking at Stephen Blundell's book "Concepts in Thermal Physics" which seems to be of a similar level, except the topics are split into smaller groups. Have you heard of it? How do you think it compares?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with that particular book, I'm afraid.

Comment: There is a course of  statistical mechanics in youTube with 10 videos, from prof. Leonard Susskind. That derivation is well done there.

Comment: This is maybe a bit of self promotion but I one wrote a note that proves it with very little overhead. https://scholar.harvard.edu/files/noahmiller/files/statistical_mechanics.pdf

Comment: How is the upper equation $-\log\Big(\frac{N_i}{N}\Big) \propto \frac{E_i}{T}$ intuitive to you? This, as the wiki says, comes from Maxwell-Boltzmann statistics, meaning the derivation of the Boltzmann distribution, the setting up of which is the 'hardest' part of the whole derivation, are you sure you appreciate [where it comes from](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%E2%80%93Boltzmann_statistics#Derivation_from_microcanonical_ensemble)?

Comment: @bolbteppa A very late response, but it's intuitive to me as $-log(\frac{N_i}{N}) = log(\frac{N}{N_i})$ gets larger for single particle microstates that have low numbers of particles, which fits the expression on the right hand side which gets larger as the energy you're searching for gets larger for some fixed temperature. Perhaps we mean different things by intuitive, I mean the equation makes sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

Staring from the first part that make sense to you (this part is considered rather difficult to me!!!) :
\begin{align}
-\log\Big(\frac{N_i}{N}\Big) &\propto \frac{E_i}{K_BT}\\
\frac{N_i}{N} &\propto \exp\left( -\frac{E_i}{K_BT}\right)\\
\frac{N_i}{N} &= C \exp\left( -\frac{E_i}{K_BT}\right)
\end{align}
Where $C$  is a constant to be determined.

Then find the constant $C$ from the condition $\sum \frac{N_i}{N} = \frac{N}{N} = 1$:
\begin{align}
 1 &= \sum_i \frac{N_i}{N}\\
&= \sum_i C \exp\left( -\frac{E_i}{K_BT}\right)\\
&= C \sum_i \exp\left( -\frac{E_i}{K_BT}\right) 
\end{align}

Therefore
$$ C= \frac{1}{\sum_j \exp\big(\frac{-E_j}{k_BT}\big)}$$

And
$$
\frac{N_i}{N} = \frac{ \exp\left( -\frac{E_i}{K_BT}\right) }{ \sum_j \exp\big(\frac{-E_j}{k_BT}\big) }
$$

Comment: That's great thankyou, but where does the $k_B$ come from? Other than that though, nicely derived!

Comment: Short answer: The exponent must be a dimensionless quantity, the denominator must be added a constant to have a unit of energy. 
Long answer: This is the hard part to derive the Boltzmann distribution from micro-canonical formulation.